# How to fix 'Not Found, status=404' error when accessing Spring Boot GraphQL endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I am getting following error when I hit the endpoint: http://localhost:8080/graphiql

## **Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat May 27 14:34:41 EDT 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

In application.properties:
spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
    @QueryMapping
    public Book bookById(@Argument String id) {
        return Book.getBookById(id);
    }

    @SchemaMapping
    public Author author(Book book) {
        return Author.getById(book.authorId());
    }
}
```

Graphql Schema

```
type Book {
    id: ID
    name: String
    pageCount: Int
    author: Author
}

type Author {
    id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
}

type Query {
    getBookById(id: ID): Book
}
```

Comment: Please can you post your application.properties ?